# T-SQL @@FETCH Doesn't retrieve last value on multi delete(insert or update)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am new to T-SQL triggers.I am implementing some triggers on a table that on every insert ,update and delete process on table triggers start.

When a single delete command runs, it just works but when  multi delete occur within one sql command it doesnt retrieve the last deleted row's id(shows the previous deleted row id).

For example when i delete 4 rows with sql command , PRINT(on trigger) shows ID's like this:

```
    -Value 1 (First deleted row id)
    -Value 2 (Second deleted row id)
    -Value 3 (Third deleted row id)
    -Value 3 (**WRONG!!!** Again, Third deleted row id )(Should see last row id here)
```

Here is the delete trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES_LOG_DELETE]
ON [dbo].[GD_GREENRAIN_CODES]
AFTER DELETE
AS
DECLARE @CODEID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @COUNT int;
SET @COUNT=(SELECT count(1) FROM deleted);

DECLARE contact_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT T.CODEID FROM deleted T
set NOCOUNT ON
OPEN contact_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
INTO @CODEID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
   FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
   INTO @CODEID;

  PRINT @CODEID
  EXEC [dbo].[SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES] @CODEID,NULL,NULL,'D'
  END
CLOSE contact_cursor;
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor;

GO
```

Comment: The answer that is given is correct. I just have a question, why do you use a cursor in the trigger? What is `SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES` do? And it is not neccesary to call `SET NOCOUNT ON` twice. Once is enough

Comment: SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES is a Store Procedure that getting Action parameter(Update,Delete,Insert) and some other parameters like ID,DESC etc.. to run I,U,D processes on specific tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

`FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
INTO @CODEID;`

twice before doing anything with it.
Typically when using a cursor you do that once outside the loop and then once per iteration at the end of the iteration, but you have it at the beginning of that loop.

I think in that particular case you can fix it if you just switch the following two lines with the previously mentioned lines.

`PRINT @CODEID
EXEC [dbo].[SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES] @CODEID,NULL,NULL,'D'`

On a side note: I would strongly suggest to stick to set based operations and not trying to squeeze your business logic into sql by forcing it to work on single rows. I don't know what `SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES` does, but I am pretty sure whatever it does can also be achieved using set based operations on the whole deleted-set as opposed to each single row of it individually.

Comment: Thanks for info.I switch lines that you mentioned. When i run delete command that deletes 4 rows related to PK(Guid value) on table(has about 11k rows total) , sql server enters like infinite loop , i need to stop query that longs more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @balron and before you made that change there was no infinite loop?

Comment: Before changes same  delete query finished in a second.

Comment: @balron that sounds strange, maybe you made a typo there? Can you show how your trigger now looks as a whole? maybe on pastebin.com or something? Otherwise I could only imagine that `SP_GD_GREENRAIN_CODES` itself does trigger the trigger, too?

Comment: For a testing purpose i have also commented Store procedure line, query is still on infinite loop.
https://paste.ee/p/nQmrU

Comment: @balron it this really the code you have tried now? You have the critical lines commented out. No wonder it executes for ever. `--FETCH NEXT FROM contact_Cursor; --INTO @CODEID;` lose the `--` so the code gets executed

Comment: Sorry,pasted wrongly, FETCH NEXT FROM part is NOT commented out on my working project.As your suggest i moved PRINT @CODEID part to above , now it is working as i need , thanks.